# How to Client Side connect to Sharepoint 2010 with claim based auth

Tags: client-object-model, claims-based-auth, security-token-service, claim-provider

I had to create an application which connects to Sharepoint. The interested Sharepoint Application is set to work ONLY with claim based Authentication, so I cannot use the classic:

```
 NetworkCredential Cred = new NetworkCredential("administrator", "Password", "domain");
```

How can i connect by Claim Based?

I know I must contact STS, get a Token, contact SP STS, get another token and then contact Sharepoint...

Is there any tutorial or hint to do this in the right way?

Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 2):

Robert Bogue has written a tool and sample app I have used successfully against a claims environment. Basically he extends the ClientContext class. In my case though, I had to be on a domain-joined machine for the code to work.  Download it [here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Remote-Authentication-in-b7b6f43c).

Answer (score 1):

I think the best starting point is: [Using the Client Object Model with a Claims Based Auth Site in SharePoint 2010](http://blogs.technet.com/b/speschka/archive/2010/06/04/using-the-client-object-model-with-a-claims-based-auth-site-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx)